# eclipse android update error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I updated my android SDK yesterday from eclipse, and then went to do an eclipse update and got this error:

An internal error occurred during: "Updating Software".

```
Profile SDKProfile is not current. Expected timestamp 1341934208292 but was 1341934208292.
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this [bug discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269468) can help you.